# Android - App with obfuscated AAR library is crashing when minifyEnabled true causes java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, minify, aar

I have an android app that uses CSRMesh Library as an AAR module. The AAR itself is obfuscated. My app works fine when `minifyEnabled` is **false** in `build.gradle` but when I set it to **true** the app is crashing.

The following code is from a custom `MeshLibraryManager` class for making API calls to the library.

```
private void enableBluetooth() {
    try {
        mCurrentChannel = MeshChannel.BLUETOOTH;
        isChannelReady = false;
        mBtBearer = new BluetoothBearer(this, mContext.get());
        if (mService != null) {
            mService.setBearer(mBtBearer);  // crash occurs in this line
            mService.setBluetoothBearerEnabled(mBtBearer);
        }
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new MeshSystemEvent(MeshSystemEvent.SystemEvent.CHANNEL_NOT_READY));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In this code block, `mService` is an instance of the `MeshService` class from the library.
I have added a comment in the line where the app crashes. If I comment out that line and the line below it the app doesn't crash but then I'm not able to perform the required Bluetooth operations.

This is the complete stack trace of the crash:

```
2021-05-14 16:21:48.994 27372-27372/com.example.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myApp, PID: 27372
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.csr.internal.mesh_le.g0.a(SourceFile:70)
        at com.csr.internal.mesh_le.f.l(SourceFile:269)
        at com.csr.csrmesh2.MeshService.y(SourceFile:309)
        at com.example.scanner.api.MeshLibraryManager.v(SourceFile:336)
        at com.example.scanner.api.MeshLibraryManager.o(SourceFile:59)
        at com.example.scanner.api.MeshLibraryManager$b.onServiceConnected(SourceFile:595)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1738)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
```

I have tried adding proguard rules for the required classes whichever I could figure from code and stack trace but nothing works.

Please suggest how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ensure that the following line will be there in your proguard rules. This will tell your application to ensure that the SpongyCastle encryption libraries can be used.

```
-keep class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.** { *; }
```